# Implement Unobtrusive Javascript with Parameters

Tags: javascript, extjs

What's your strategy for passing parameters to unobtrusive Javascript?

Say we have three dynamically generated input fields which need to be validated for ranges:

```
<input id="smallValue" class="validatedRange" />
<input id="mediumValue" class="validatedRange" />
<input id="largeValue" class="validatedRange" />
```

In the Javascript:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
  Ext.select("input.validatedRange").on("change", function () {
    // How to get the min/max values to here?
  }); 
});
```

Somehow, the min/max values need to be included in the markup. The "best" way I see currently is to abuse the tag like so:

```
<input id="smallValue" class="validatedRange" min="0" max="10" />
<input id="mediumValue" class="validatedRange" min="100" max="1000" />
<input id="largeValue" class="validatedRange" min="1000" max="10000" />
```

Do you know of a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of having custom HTML attributes, there are the data-prefixed attributes...

```
<input id="foo" class="bar" data-min="100" data-max="1000">
```

This is a new feature of HTML5: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

I never agree with invalid HTML markup, so i'ma suggest this..

not 100% sure if it would work but it should in theory): look into the jquery validation library for your validation needs (save hand-rolling something!)
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/

this is all done declaratively and is quite a neat way to do things

also you could checkout live query which rebinds events when things are inserted into the DOM dynamically
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

the combo of these two *should* work. hope that helps